# VB ASP declaring multiple variables in one If Then statement

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, if-statement, asp-classic

Im working with some old VB today on an ASP website.

my code is as follows:

```
arrRows = Split(sRows,",")
If arrRows(0) = "honesty" Then
honesty1= arrRows(1)
End If
If arrRows(0) = "honesty" Then
honesty2= arrRows(2)
End If
If arrRows(0) = "honesty" Then
honesty3= arrRows(3)
End If
```

I want to narrow this down to one If Then statement, can I assign more then one variable in a single If Then statement? If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do more than add 1 variable in an If Then statement.

```
arrRows = Split(sRows,",")
If arrRows(0) = "honesty" Then
    honesty1= arrRows(1)
    honesty2= arrRows(2)
    honesty3= arrRows(3)
End If
```